# Convert a string to number and back to string?

Tags: php, string, encoding, perfect-hash

I would like to know how I can convert a short ASCII string to a number (int, float, or numeric string). I saw a couple of [posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864185/string-to-number-and-back-algorithm) mentioned [perfect hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) which seems like it [might be what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994921/perfect-hash-function-for-urls/3011311#3011311). However, I'm not quite understanding the math for this.

**How could you convert an ASCII string into a sequence of numbers and then back to a string?**

As a side note, breaking a string down into it's ASCII character numbers is easy enough.

```
foreach(str_split($string) as $char) $number .= ord($char);
```

#### Update

After more reading I came up with this. However, I'm wondering if there are anyways to **shorten the number sequence** so it's not quite as long.

```
class intnum
{
    public static $charset = array(
        32 => ' ', 33 => '!', 34 => '"', 35 => '#', 36 => '$',
        37 => '%', 38 => '&', 39 => "'", 40 => '(', 41 => ')',
        42 => '*', 43 => '+', 44 => ',', 45 => '-', 46 => '.',
        47 => '/', 48 => '0', 49 => '1', 50 => '2', 51 => '3',
        52 => '4', 53 => '5', 54 => '6', 55 => '7', 56 => '8',
        57 => '9', 58 => ':', 59 => ';', 60 => '<', 61 => '=',
        62 => '>', 63 => '?', 64 => '@', 65 => 'A', 66 => 'B',
        67 => 'C', 68 => 'D', 69 => 'E', 70 => 'F', 71 => 'G',
        72 => 'H', 73 => 'I', 74 => 'J', 75 => 'K', 76 => 'L',
        77 => 'M', 78 => 'N', 79 => 'O', 80 => 'P', 81 => 'Q',
        82 => 'R', 83 => 'S', 84 => 'T', 85 => 'U', 86 => 'V',
        87 => 'W', 88 => 'X', 89 => 'Y', 90 => 'Z', 91 => '[',
        92 => '\\', 93 => ']', 94 => '^', 95 => '_', 96 => '`',
        97 => 'a', 98 => 'b', 99 => 'c', 100 => 'd', 101 => 'e',
        102 => 'f', 103 => 'g', 104 => 'h', 105 => 'i', 106 => 'j',
        107 => 'k', 108 => 'l', 109 => 'm', 110 => 'n', 111 => 'o',
        112 => 'p', 113 => 'q', 114 => 'r', 115 => 's', 116 => 't',
        117 => 'u', 118 => 'v', 119 => 'w', 120 => 'x', 121 => 'y',
        122 => 'z', 123 => '{', 124 => '|', 125 => '}'
    );

    public static function fromNumber($number)
    {
        $string = '';
        while($number)
        {
            $value = substr($number, 0, 2);
            $number = substr($number, 2);

            if($value < 32)
            {
                $value .= substr($number, 0, 1);
                $number = substr($number, 1);
            }

            $string .= self::$charset[ (int) $value];
        }
        return $string;
    }

    public static function fromString($string)
    {
        $number = '';
        foreach(str_split($string) as $char) $number .= ord($char);
        return $number;
    }
}

$string = 'this is my test string to convert';

$number = intnum::fromString($string);
$string = intnum::fromNumber($number);
```

Comment: Why not use the code you just posted?

Comment: @Brad, how do I get the string back?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A string-to-number encoder as one-liner (PHP 5.3 style):

```
$numbers = implode(array_map(function ($n) { return sprintf('%03d', $n); },
                          unpack('C*', $str)));
```

It simply converts every byte into its decimal number equivalent, zero-padding it to a fixed length of 3 digits so it can be unambiguously converted back.

The decoder back to a string:

```
$str = implode(array_map('chr', str_split($numbers, 3)));
```

Example text:

> Wörks wíth all ストリングズ
>   087195182114107115032119195173116104032097108108032227130185227131136227131170227131179227130176227130186

Comment: hmmm, doesn't seem to work with the unicode characters you provided.

Comment: Works fine, as long as you make sure you interpret the result in the same encoding as it was input.

Comment: See http://codepad.org/wXA9ViFu (written in PHP 5.2 style, since Codepad doesn't run 5.3 yet).

Comment: Works in PHP 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just ORD chars into a string of numbers and expect it to come back because some chars may be on 2 characters and others 3.

For example:

Kang-HO will give you: 10797106103457279

Now how do you know it's not: 10-79-71-0-61-0-34-57-27-9?

You need to either pad all your numbers in 3 number codes and thus get: 107097106103045072079
and then break it apart in blocks of 3 numbers and then ASC them back...

Comment: @PhilLello, do you see any way to alter my code above using hex?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to convert your string into a sequence of **integers** you must use always a fixed block of numbers. In this case 3 since ASCII uses a 8 bit words, therefore, the maximun possible integer is 2^8-1 = 255.

You should fill the unsed space with 0:

```
function zero_fill($num){
    if($num <= 9) $num = "00".$num;
    elseif($num <= 99) $num = "0".$num;
    return $num;
}
```

You can use the function you have created in conjuction with this one, and to recover the string, take block of 3 integers and convert them back to its correspondant ASCII character.

```
foreach(str_split($numberSeq, 3) as $asciiIntValue) $stringBack .= chr($asciiIntValue);
```

Comment: "11bit words"? 2^11-1 = 127? I think you derailed a little there.

Comment: Was about to write it too, 2^11 = 2048... you meant 2^7 but then again, ASCII has 255 characters buddy so it's 2^8...